# Visual Studio - how to create a new platfrom that derives from x64 and sets additional preprocessor definition

Tags: c++, visual-studio, configuration, c-preprocessor, platform

I'v been struggling with correctly configuring Visual Studio (2013 and 2015) to be able to create a new Build Platform based on the x64 preset which in addition adds a preprocessor definition (c++) macro to the build commandline. 
What I want is to be able to select a new Platform from the dropdown menu, but a new one which is not Win32 or ARM. In my C++ code I use a macro (_SSE4) to compile math functions optimized for SSE4.

The first problem I have is that I cant create a new Platform in the Configuration manager named x64_SSE4:
[image: error message]

Error message: New project platforms cannot be created because this new solution platform is not supported by any of the projects.

I don't want to create a new solution configuration with DebugSSE4 and ReleaseSS4 because I dont want to have 4+ different configurations (including the normal Debug & Release configurations). This new platform should be valid for each project in the solution.

If creating a new Platform with a new name would work, i could create a new PropertySheet which checks for $(Platform) == "x64_SSE4" and then set the preprocessor definiton by hand.

Is there a more elegant way to introduce a new platform with preprocessor definitions?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No, use the upper left combo.

Comment: what do you mean with upper left combo? The configuration combobox? Could you please be a bit more specific? Thanks

Comment: You can add as many solution configurations as you like and name them whatever you prefer.  But not solution platforms, as it tells you, the platform selection determines which build tools (compiler, linker, etc) are used.  That's a fixed set.

Comment: Thats very unfortunate, I wanted to avoid creating so many configurations.

Comment: Still, if I have my own compiler `myCompiler.exe`, and my own linker `myLinker.exe`, etc., I should be able to create my own platform `myPlatform`, right?  How is that done?